# 'Satire' is to 'Satirically' as 'Parody is to ...?

Tags: adverbs, derivational-morphology

As stated in the title; I'm having a difficult time thinking of the equivalent conjugation.
The word "Satire" is to "Satirically" as "Parody" is to ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for **[parodically](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parody)**.

Comment: Any reason to choose parodistic over parodic? Not criticising your choice, just curious to know whether there are subtle differences

Comment: @Dancrumb: None particularly - I was actually just editing to use (what on second thought I considered to be) the 'easier' form.

Comment: My impression,  despite that this is the best answer, is that these extensions of 'parody' are not accepted words. I think this is a glaring lexical gap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an official word, but *parodiably* might be correct. This is based on the related forms section of the definition here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Parody

Also further down there is the word *parodical*, so *parodically* is a valid construction.

Also a parody can can be a satire, so sometimes satirically is the word you want.

Answer (score 0):

"Sardonically" could carries a connotation of disdain that is not always present in parody, and also doesn't necessarily imply imitation. What about "mocking" or "mockingly"?